# Is it possible to have a property on a singleton object that has a different scope?

Tags: structuremap

I have the following object:

```
CommandA (Singleton)
    IFoo Foo (PerRequest)
```

I would like a proxy object to be injected into the singleton so that when I call Foo, it will give me the foo object that is specific to my request.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, all injections in a singleton *should be* singleton.
First of all, if you `CommandA` is singleton, the injected objects would be singleton.
Now if you say you need a new object per request, you would probably have a Factory (Singleton) in your CommandA which would create a new object or get proxy reference upon each call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In spring/java, you can inject a factory bean. The framework uses the factory bean and creates a proxy object that dynamically gets the scoped object.  The nice thing about this technique is that it keeps the factory out of the class and this appears transparent to the developer using/creating the singleton command.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As Anshu says, it sounds like you're really after a factory bahaviour. One way to implement it would be like this:

The command:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
   private Func<IFoo> _fooProvider;

   public Command(Func<IFoo> fooProvider){ _fooProvider = fooProvider; }

   public IFoo Foo { get{ return _fooProvider(); }}
}
```

In your configuration:

```
For<ICommand>().Singleton().Use<Command>();
For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
```

StructureMap will automatically inject the Func, since the IFoo is configured.